# Vue.js e2e w Nightwatch.js how to get details on WebElements (WebDriver protocol)?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nightwatch.js, end-to-end

During my 2e2 tests w Nightwatch.js, I can get elements using the WebDriver protocol , but the result ( res.value ) is an array of elements ids...

How can I get the details of these elements ?

```
[ { ELEMENT: '0.03261545200301663-4' },
  { ELEMENT: '0.03261545200301663-5' } ] ' length: ' 2
FIRST ELEMENT ID:  0.03261545200301663-4
FIRST ELEMENT TAG NAME:  undefined
```

**e2e/test.js**

```
    module.exports = {

      'Add shoppinglist': (browser) => {
        const devServer = browser.globals.devServerURL
        // open the browser and wait for #app to be on the page
        browser.url(devServer).waitForElementVisible('#app', 5000)
        // check the title of the current active tab
        browser.expect.element('ul.nav-tabs li.active a').text.to.equal('Groceries')
        // click on add shopping list plus button
        browser.click('#addShoppingListIcon')

        // get shopping list tab title elements
        browser.elements('css selector', 'ul.nav-tabs li', (res) => {
          console.log(res.value, ' length: ', res.value.length)
          console.log('FIRST ELEMENT ID: ', res.value[0].ELEMENT)
          console.log('FIRST ELEMENT TAG NAME: ', res.value[0].tag_name)
          console.log('FIRST ELEMENT CSS CLASS: ', res.value[0].style('class'))
        })

        browser.pause(1000)
        // check the title of the active tab
        browser.expect.element('ul.nav-tabs li.active a').text.to.equal('New Shopping List')
        // check the title of the active content panel
        browser.expect.element('#app .tab-content .tab-pane.active h2').text.to.equal('New Shopping List')
        // check the default value of the footer change title input field
        browser.getValue('#app .tab-content .tab-pane.active .footer input.input[name=title]', (result) => {
          browser.assert.equal(result.value, 'New Shopping List')
        })
        browser.end()
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Should use the ELEMENT as the id for subsequent requests ...

```
    browser.elements('css selector', 'ul.nav-tabs li', (res) => {
      console.log(res.value, ' length: ', res.value.length)
      console.log('FIRST ELEMENT ID: ', res.value[0].ELEMENT)
      browser.elementIdAttribute(res.value[0].ELEMENT, 'class', (value) => {
        console.log('FIRST ELEMENT CLASS ATTRIBUTE: ', value)
      })
    })

    console.log
    FIRST ELEMENT CLASS ATTRIBUTE:  { sessionId: '13a05b81a71d8860df5432fc7e585ab5',
      status: 0,
      value: 'active' }
```